# How do I find if a taxonomy term is used?

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

I'm using drupal6 taxonomy.The content type 'B' is using a tag field which can use the title of the some of nodes of the content type 'A'.If any node of 'B' tagged a name or title of a node of content type 'A', I want to display one message in the respective node of 'A'.

Alternatively, is there any way to find if www.mysite/category/tag/term doesn't gives the "Page not found" error? This is to find if the term is used, or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I want to thank whom all gave response to my post.And my answer is,I get the title from the url of content type 'A'(wwww.sitename.com/xxx/yyy/title-raw i get the value of title-raw that is the title of that node.)
And the taxonomy term page of content type 'B' has the url as www.sitename.com/category/content_type_b_machine_name/term name.
so i checked the last term of the taxonomy term page in its url with the title-raw of content-type 'A'
If the www.sitename.com/category/content_type_b_machine_name/title-raw-con-type-A doesnot gives a "400" (page not found error)page then the title is used as a taxonomy term.

Comment: If anyone know a better answers than mine,Please don't forget to share with us.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the term name, you can use the following code.

```
$nodes = array();

if ($term = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($term_name)) {
  $result = taxonomy_select_nodes(array($term->tid), 'or', 0, FALSE, 'n.sticky DESC, n.created DESC');
  while ($row = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    $nodes[] = $row->nid;
  }
}

if (!empty($nodes)) {
  // The taxonomy term is used from at least a node.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you could use the function [drupal_http_request](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/6) (in a module or in a template).

This functions returns the response of the request (200 if it's ok, and so on).

Comment: @arrubiu.Thanks for your response,if i want to check this link www.mysite.com/category/tags gives a page not found or not,how to use this drupal_http_request? If my question sounds bad please forgive me.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `taxonomy_get_term_by_name('term name')`. It should return an empty array if no term is found, so just check with the `empty()` function.